# PCG Random Number Generator and Xcode Undefined symbols (unable to find Kernel)

Tags: c, xcode, random

Before asking the question I have to say that I'm currently using Xcode 6.2 on Yosemite.

I have been experiencing this problem also with another C code of mine which involved the generation of random numbers.

So, I wanted to use [this famous library](http://www.pcg-random.org) to generate random numbers (In particular I'm trying to compile the file called pcg32-demo.c that you can find in the download of [Minimal C Implementation 0.9](http://www.pcg-random.org/download.html) having in the same folder pcg_basic.c). I created the project with Xcode and compiled. Then I got the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_pcg32_boundedrand_r", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcg32_random_r", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcg32_srandom_r", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled a bit and it seems that I had to change the Architecture to Universal. Unfortunately it doesn't change a lot because I get the same error for 32bit

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386
```

Then I googled again, thus I added Frameworks and Libraries. Since I didn't know which one I needed, I added all of them. However, I get this error message:

```
ld: framework not found Kernel
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Which is kind of strange! I'm quite sure the RNG doesn't involve the Kernel.

In order to compile I used both gcc `gcc pcg32-demo.c` from terminal and the "play" button in Xcode. From the latter I also get the following:

```
Ld /Users/edwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testPCG-eygvqldhuakrfqakhmugrepbwsbt/Build/Products/Debug/testPCG normal x86_64
cd /Users/edwin/Documents/CodeZRPring/Testnewrandom/testPCG
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/edwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testPCG-eygvqldhuakrfqakhmugrepbwsbt/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/edwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testPCG-eygvqldhuakrfqakhmugrepbwsbt/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/edwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testPCG-eygvqldhuakrfqakhmugrepbwsbt/Build/Intermediates/testPCG.build/Debug/testPCG.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/testPCG.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/edwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testPCG-eygvqldhuakrfqakhmugrepbwsbt/Build/Intermediates/testPCG.build/Debug/testPCG.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/testPCG_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/edwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testPCG-eygvqldhuakrfqakhmugrepbwsbt/Build/Products/Debug/testPCG
```

Does anyone have any idea why I get this error messages? Is it related only with random numbers?

Comment: `In particular I'm trying to compile the file called pcg_basic.c` are you trying to compile that file alone? remember, there is no `main()` there.

Comment: Please show how you're compiling. I think the error is from the linker, isn't it?

Comment: I changed the edit! I hope there is what you are looking for (I'm not kind an expert of this things :-( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting the error from the linker. The problem is, you're compiling the `pcg32-demo.c` file alone and not linking it against the other object files contaning the required definition of the functions used in `pcg32-demo.c`.

Solution:

---

EDIT:

After the valuable comment from Mr. **@trojanfoe**, it seems you need to either

- Add the required files to the project in Xcode which contains the function definitions.
- Link against a library containing the function definitions required for linking and generating the binary.

---

Otherwise,

1. [Short and easy way] Use the makefile provided.
2. [Long and complex way] Compile each of the required source files, generate the object files and then link them together to produce the binary.

Comment: Not really a solution.  "Link with the library containing those symbols" is the answer that involves keeping Xcode.

Comment: @trojanfoe I did not get you. Can you kindly elaborate a bit?

Comment: Well asking the OP to use `make` rather than Xcode is avoiding the issue, and the OP will likely get similar issues when using the library with other Xcode project.  The question cannot be answered as there isn't enough information.

Comment: @trojanfoe OK. I got that part (however I don't have any idea of Xcode, guess it's an IDE). However, by seeing `gcc pcg32-demo.c`, I thought OP might be missing other object files for linking.

Comment: Yes he is missing other symbols.  He needs to add those source files to the Xcode project or he needs to link with a library.  The OP doesn't understand the error message it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm quite a newbie :-(. Can you tell me which files I have to add and how? Because I get this error quite often also for other codes of mine.

Comment: Yeah I guess, although it looks like the OP needs a bit more help.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I understood the concept but I don't know which files I should include and how. I did the "make" command from the terminal and now I have some *.o files.

Comment: @edwineveningfall you don't need to concentrate on `*.o` files, as of now. You should be having the binary called `pcg32-demo` or simmilar. you can try running that.

Comment: @edwineveningfall See, to generate a binary (executable), you need to take all the object files (`*.o`) contaning all the required function definitions and link them together to produce the binary.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was able to run the binary program!! However, in general, I wanted to use that library for RNG inside codes of mine. I guess I will have the same errors if I don't know how to properly link the files (and which files?) from gcc or Xcode. Can you expand a bit on that?

Comment: I think I was able to include the files in Xcode (just some drag and drop) I will let you know!

Comment: Yes that was the solution: when one creates the project with Xcode, simply drag the libraries and related *c files in the same folder as main.c